# 'Customer Support' vs 'Customer Service'

Tags: meaning

'Customer Support' vs 'Customer Service'

I'm curious the different meaning What is exactly different? When use?

Comment: Customer support vs customer service: https://www.marketingtechblog.com/service-vs-support/

Comment: There is no "exactly" in a question like this. I'm sure you can find definitions of both, but they won't agree with each other, and the two sets may well overlap.

Comment: They're pretty much the same in British English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refe*rence-businessdictionary.com*

[**Customer service**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_service) is the *[provision](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/customer-service.html)* of service to customers before, during and after a purchase.

**[Customer support](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/customer-support.html)**: is broadly a range of *customer services* to assist customers in making cost effective and correct use of a product. It includes assistance in planning, installation, training, trouble shooting, maintenance, upgrading, and disposal of a product.

Regarding technology products such as mobile phones, televisions, and computers, etc. it is termed as **technical support.**

> *You would also come across "customer service and support ", a company's customer relationship management department.*

Comment: Good distinction Mysti.  I would also remark that Customer Support may include technical support services.